# Looping through JSON object in Swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I got this JSON object which I sent from my server to my Swift application.

```
{
  "625289": {
    "id": 1,
    "subject": "Hello World"
  },
  "625277": {
    "id": 2,
    "subject":"Bye World!"
  }
}
```

So i tried to get the subject for each result ("625289" and "625277") by doing as below in my Swift class:

```
struct Resultat : Decodable   {
  let subject: String
}

var result = [Resultat]()
let urlll = URL(string:"http://localhost:8888/api/pouet.php")

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlll!) { (data, response, error) in
  do {
    print("coucoulol")
    //print(response)

    self.result = try JSONDecoder().decode([Resultat].self, from: data!)

    print(self.result)

    for eachTicket in self.result {
      print(eachTicket.subject)
    }
  } catch {
    print("error"+error.localizedDescription)
  }
}.resume()
```

However, when I tried to execute the code, it says "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." From what I understand, the loop for in the code is suffice to get the values in the arrays or maybe I'm wrong. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: it's weird..because i already verify this JSON here http://json.parser.online.fr/ and it didn't give me any errors...FYI, I already tried adding `[ and ] ` in the JSON but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root object is a dictionary. You can decode the object to `[String:Resultat]`. The dictionary contains also dictionaries. An array is not involved.

```
struct Resultat : Decodable {
    let subject: String
    let id : Int
}
```

---

```
...
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:Resultat].self, from: data!)
for (key, value) in result {
    print(key, value.subject)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response...I have another question, let's say I add a new variable in one of the key in the dictionary, like `"date": "13/07/2017"` , how do I get the date in Swift given that the other key doesn't have the same variable? @vadian

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: So I have a dictionary like this, one of the key has a variable "date" `{
  "625289": {
    "id": 1,
    "subject": "Hello World", "date": "1/1/2018"
  },
  "625277": {
    "id": 2,
    "subject":"Bye World!"
  }
}` it's when i tried to get the "date" into my Swift application by using your solution above, it shows an error like "the data isn't in a correct format"... so that's why i think it's because maybe the other key doesn't have the variable date..thank you in advance @vadian

Comment: Add an optional property: `let date : String?`. You can even declare `let date : Date?` and add the appropriate `dateDecodingStrategy` to the `JSONDecoder`

Comment: it works great...why i never thought about this in the first place..thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can try using **SwiftyJSON** below

$0.0 = Key

$0.1 = value

```
let data = JSON(result)
data.dictionaryValue.forEach({
     print($0.1)
})
```