# SWIFT: Iterate through a JSON object that's convert to a dictionary

Tags: json, swift

**NOTE:** Somewhat similar questions have been already asked. And yet none of them provides how to solve this seemingly simple task. So I hope it gets resolved here once and for all.
**MY PROBLEM:**
I am receiving this nested JSON object:
[image]

```
  print("type(of: JSON) \( type(of: JSON))") //__NSDictionaryI
  completion(true, nil, JSON as? [String: Any], nil)
```

Alamofire module converts it, as you see, to a Dictionary.
I have been trying for hours on end to access the nested values with different methods (Something, I thought that should be straightforward compared to JavaScript), inside this Dictionary but I couldn't find a single way that works.
So except for the high-level values, I couldn't access anything else:

```
for (key,movieData) in moviesData! { // moviesData is the JSON dictionary object
    // Do some logic
   }
```

**So is there anyway to easily manipulate/access the received JSON data?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looping through JSON object in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47326354/looping-through-json-object-in-swift)

Comment: Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111627/iterating-through-a-dictionary-in-swift

Comment: Stop using dictionaries, declare structs and use `Decodable` to parse the dictionary into structs. In javascript, objects and dictionaries are the same thing, it's not the same for other languages. https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37 Also, Alamofire is no longer needed for iOS projects. Settings up a `URLSession` is not more difficult than using Alamofire.

Answer (score 0):

This is a far from being an ideal solution but it works. So here it is:

```
  for (key,movieData) in moviesData! {
            if let nestedDictionary = moviesData![key] as? [String: Any] {
                print("nestedDictionary: ",nestedDictionary) // logs the result part of the JSON object
                // Trying to access nested values
                for (key,value) in nestedDictionary {
                    print("nestedDictionary.key: ",key)
                    print("nestedDictionary.type(of:value): ",type(of:value) )
                    print("nestedDictionary.value: ",value)
                    // Testing if sections is an array of dictionaries
                    if let arrayOfDictionaries = nestedDictionary[key] as? [[String: Any]] {
                        print("nestedDictionary: ",nestedDictionary) // logs the result part of the JSON object
                        // Trying to access array items which are sections
                        for item in arrayOfDictionaries {
                            print("arrayOfDictionaries.item: ",item)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

It is based on the tip mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37):

```
if let dictionary = jsonWithObjectRoot as? [String: Any] {
    if let number = dictionary["someKey"] as? Double {
        // access individual value in dictionary
    }

    for (key, value) in dictionary {
        // access all key / value pairs in dictionary
    }

    if let nestedDictionary = dictionary["anotherKey"] as? [String: Any] {
        // access nested dictionary values by key
    }
}
```

The **key idea** is to check if there's a nested dictionary or a nested array inside the json and then iterate accordingly.